# Justify more than one item inside a td in different directions, HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to left-justify one item, and right-justify the other item inside a single td. Is that doable? Thanks.

**test.php**

```
<table border = '1'>

<tr><td>Left-justified Right-justified</td></tr>
<tr><td>TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT</td></tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
<table border = '1'>

<tr>
<td>
    <span >Left-justified</span>
    <span  style="float:right;"> Right-justified</span>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
    TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: I could just kiss you right now. Thanks! Tried everywhere, and found really complex, really weird answers that didn't work. This one is very simple, and works perfectly. Exactly what I was looking for.